# Key differences between DualShock 4 v1 and v2

Tags: ps4, controllers

I've searched Internet for about 15 minutes, but I  must be doing something wrong, because I can't find precise information on what are the differences between DualShock 4 version 1 and version 2?

I see a lot of offers in my country for purchasing Playstation 4 with two controllers in a package and when browsing offers details it turns out that only one controller is version 2 and second one is version 1. As a complete PS-newbie I was thinking, if this isn't some kind of scam?

Comment: Are you asking what the differences are between the controllers are as indicated by the title or if this is a scam as you say at the end of your question? The latter would seem to be off topic I believe.

Comment: I don't think it's a scam, V1 DS4s are still great. There aren't many noticeable differences, the easiest one to see is that the V2's lightbar shines through a translucent stripe in the touchpad so you can see the color while using the gamepad normally. Apparently there were also improvements to the thumbstick rubber grips and the battery life, but I've never noticed any differences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/92xooh/is_the_dualshock_4_v2_much_better_than_the_v1/) contains a few differences. The ones standing out the most are:

> Longer battery life, more durable rubber on the analog sticks, theres
>   a light bar on the face of the touch pad, and the controller is also a
>   little lighter. The biggest issue with the V1 is that the rubber on
>   the analog would wear around the edges and then eventually peal off.

These claims are also supported by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DualShock#DualShock_4)

---

<sub>Found with "dualshock 4 version 1 vs version 2"</sub>

Comment: Can confirm the rubber on the analog sticks on the v1 was awful, and when it started to come away it was a nightmare. I think for a while Sony were offering free replacements of the analog sticks, it was that much of a problem.

Comment: I've only had the v1's, so I got *really* worried when I saw the touch pad would have a light bar... Thankfully its thin and dim; not like the blinding monstrosity I imagined. And as for the analog rubber... yeah, it's pretty bad. Ended up putting third party covers over them after one of them started peeling apart. Work really well actually.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to notice is that the V2 controller has wired connection when you connect it via USB to the console. The V1 controller only charges via the cable but stays wireless. This might help especially if you're playing games that require precise real-time inputs.